# Expresso Store - Empty orders triggering order confirmation email - Store v2

Tags: expresso-store, email, orders

Since upgrading to Store v2 we have started to notice 'empty' order confirmation emails coming through. There are no products listed and the value of the order is £0.

Checking the admin these orders are being marked as paid, but the customer and order details are blank. I'm not sure if this is a result of the upgrade, or if some naughty external script has just found the site and knows what php scripts to call to trigger the emails.

Grabs of the empty orders in the admin follow:

Order list - notice the green 'yes' paid marker.
[image]

Order detail page
[image]

Comment: Interesting. Have you had a look through your server logs at when these orders are being submitted and on what url?

Comment: Hi Adrian, There is nothing in the logs that jumps out at me, though you might know better what to look for. I can send you the access logs privately if you'd like to have a look?

Comment: Tomtids, did you find the answer to this? We are experiencing the same problem so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Dan. I'm afraid we found no cause for this. But it seems to have stopped happening!